# how to upgrade testlink from 1.9.3 to 1.9.4,on windows?

Tags: testing

I have a problem when upgrade!

```
Read/write permissions

For security reason we suggest that directories tagged with [S] on following messages, will be made UNREACHEABLE from browser
Checking if C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.4\gui\templates_c directory exists OK
Checking if C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.4\gui\templates_c directory is writable (by user used to run webserver process)    OK
Checking if /var/testlink/logs/ directory exists [S]    Failed!
Checking if /var/testlink/upload_area/ directory exists [S] Failed!
```

help me, please.
ths.

Comment: You may help other people by givig "how", thanks for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *testlinkDir* as TestLink's installation dir:

1. Open the file *testlinkDir/config.inc.php*;
2. change the values for $tlCfg->log_path and $g_repositoryPath as follows:

   ```
   ...
   $tlCfg->log_path = 'testlinkDir/logs/';
   ...
   $g_repositoryPath = 'testlinkDir/upload_area/';
   ```

It worked for me under a simple XAmpp installation in Win7.